# whenever I try to install npm it throws the following error,

Tags: ssl, npm, ssl-certificate

npm install @angular/cli

npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

thank you

Comment: did this issue resolved for you? If so, can you provide details or solution that worked?

Comment: :) too soon to ask before trying - well, for me, it worked with running the same via VPN for my work laptop. This was not working or happening on my work laptop without connecting to VPN although I was able to access internet, YouTube and all global regular internet accesses including emails.

Answer (score 0):

There are some network issue you can use open network for this or you firewall blocked it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `ssl` is `true`, so execute below command to set it to `false`.

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: Isn't SSL important? What should we keep in mind when disabling it?